# Common catch block for two methods with return type?

Tags: java, exception, java-8, try-catch

I have two methods as :

```
 ApiResponse methodA(){
    try{
    .....
    .....
    }
    catch(Exception e){
   handleException(e) // getting error here as return is missing
    }
  
    }
```

There is methodB which does different work but same catch block as above.

```
private void handleException(Exception e){
 if (ex instanceof Exception_A) {
   throw new Service_Exception_A();
}

 else if (ex instanceof Exception_B) {
throw new Service_Exception_B();

}

else if (ex instanceof Exception_C) {
throw new Service_Exception_C();

}
.......
......
else{
throw ex;
}
```

Now I am getting the error where handleException() method is called in MethodA and Method B saying that `"return statement is missing"`

If i copy paste the catch block in each of method, then it works fine,but isnt java intelligent enough to see that the handleException will always throw exception, so no need of return statement in catch block of method A and method B.What am I missing here and how can I get this work?

Comment: No, Java compiler is not intelligent enough. But you may make `handleException` that returns an exception, and your catch block throws whatever `handleException` returns.

Comment: `void handleException(Exception e) { ... throw e; }` wouldn't work anyway since `e` would need to be declared via `throws Exception` or be wrapped in a `RuntimeException`.

Comment: @Thomas, even if `handleException` declares a throw, Java compiler will not consider it as an always-throwing function. There's no such metric for methods in Java.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov yupp, just wanted to add the side note :) You're right that the compiler cannot know the code is always throwing - at least not in every case

Comment: *"return statement is missing"* - are you returning from the `try` block inside methods `methodA` and `methodB`? `Service_Exception_A`, `Service_Exception_B`, etc. extend `RuntimeException`?

Answer (score 3):

You should change `handleException` to be something like:

```java
    private <T> T handleException(Exception e){
        // ...
    }
```

this way the compiler will check that you only throw exceptions and do not return any values in the body of `handleException` method, because there is no way to construct a new instance of abstract type `T` (you can return `null`, but `null` is always an explicit escape hatch in Java).

In your `methodA` and `methodB` you should return in the `catch`-block:

```java
    ApiResponse methodA(){
        try {
            ...
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return handleException(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Or just do what M. Prokhorov was suggesting, i.e. return the exception and throw it. Since the exceptions aren't declared this would mean they are all `RuntimeException`s anyway so instead of `return handleException(e)` it could be a more explicit `throw handleException(e)` :) (of course this doesn't work for multiple different checked exceptions that should be declared explicitly).